# Android- print out values of an array

Tags: android, arrays

I am new in programming Android. I am developing an app that you want to capture sound and analyzes it. The amplitude of the sound for each time is stored in an array. These are the data needed to analyze . My question is: How I show the values of the array in wich the sound is saved?

Comment: Please post some relevant code block.

Comment: where/how are you showing the values? console? log? somewhere in your UI?

Comment: I wanted to show the data in a table for the user

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length ; i++ )
    Log.i("value" , Integer.toString(array[i]))
```

Comment: you're just printing the value of i.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you want to output the values.  You could choose to create a RecyclerView instance in your GUI and connect the array with an adapter (read [here](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/first-glance-androids-recyclerview)) or you could choose to format that information into a String and insert the text into a TextView using the setText(String) method.

Edit: Based on your comment it sounds like you should look at the Recylcer View.  You will need the following things.

- A layout file containing a Recycler View.
- A ViewHolder class that extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder - this is used to display your content in individual items of the list
- An adapter class that extends RecyclerView.Adapter - this connects your array to the ViewHolder

Some links to help you get on the way with RecyclerView:

1. [A first glance at RecyclerView](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/first-glance-androids-recyclerview)
2. [TwoWay View](http://lucasr.org/2014/07/31/the-new-twowayview/)

They do a much better job explaining and showing how the code will work then I will writing it again here.

Comment: The information for the user , should be a table . Each time the amplitude of the corresponding sound. I do not know what will be most appropriate of the options that you mentioned you . Could help me . Very grateful

Comment: thank you for your response . Could put the code please ? I have difficulties in Android code
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: I've added additional links that can help you on the way.  They do a better job showing how to write code for a RecyclerView then I will here.

Comment: Thank you for all your help and attention. I will then work on it

Comment: I've been studying the code of the links that sent me, and after installing the " Android Support Library " , continue with errors

Comment: Some of the errors concern RecyclerView---      RecyclerView.ViewHolder- cannot be resolved to a type; ListItemViewHolder-Illegal modifier for the local class ListItemViewHolder, only abstract or final is permitted.

Comment: I need to install anything else?

Comment: I would recommend asking a new question with the specific errors that you are having.   Without seeing them I couldn't begin to tell you how to fix them.